# dump CSV file from Django query to Github

Tags: python, django, git, csv

We want to automate a process through django admin where, whenever a user makes a change to a record (or adds/deletes a record), a CSV file is created and then dumped into a Github repository with a commit message specified by the person who made the change.

Creating the csv file from a queryset is easy enough... But how would we go about then getting that csv file to a folder that is git initialized so that we can commit it to a repository?

Any ideas would be great.  Essentially we're looking for a way of tracking specific changes to the database. With CSV files in github, we can really easily follow the changes, and we want to leverage that.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you can create your csv files the next step would be to talk to github via api or to have a local representation of a git repo which needs to be synct after file creation.

But if I may ask why do you want to do this with csv files in a github repo? My first response to a requirement like that would be to logg changes with the python logging infrastructure or to create an additional model to track the specific changes in the db.

Eventually this could also meet your requirements: https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Creating the csv is easy enough - but then where would I get it to live in order to push it to a git repository? I mean, I assume my static folder isn't going to be able to host a git repository on it so I can automatically push.                       However, I'll look more into django-simple-history - if it can allow us to put in "commit messages" (of sorts) - that would be a good start

Comment: I have never used simple-history but it could fit your needs. Nevertheless you could create a custom logging model to store the information you need. In the model you could use a generic foreign key to have a natural key linking to the changed object, you could still generate CSV files and store them somewhere e.g. aws s3, locally or whatever Django storage supports to store files. I just think the git/github strategy introduces an additional layer of complexity

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but have you thought of using something like [django-simple-history](http://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

It's a really easy to use Django package that tracks all Django model state on every create/update/delete. Should be much easier to get going than fiddling around pushing CSVs to github.

Comment: Thanks - I just had a look. though it isn't immediately clear to me how to add a message to a change - we'd like to have a "commit-style" message which can be used to track exactly what a person did.